# How to list the source URLs from saved html files from a folder?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, scripts

I have a lot of html files in a folder. I used them
in a project. I want to build a References.txt
file in which the URL from which each html file was saved
will be listed with the time stamp on which it was saved.
There will be a space between each URL and its corresponding
timestamp.

How can I do that from Ubuntu 12.04 using a terminal command
or shell script?

One information which can help you is that the URL from which a html
file was saved is present in the second line of the html file
and that is also visible by opening the file in a browser and then
going to source view. But I don't know how to extract it from there
using a command.

First two lines from one of those files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0084)http://www.forexrealm.com/technical-analysis/technical-indicators/typical-price.html -->
```

Comment: Please show the first 2 lines of one of these html file

Comment: See the edited post. These html files are not any special kind of html files. They are just pages saved from internet.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in a directory holding `html` files.

```
for f in *.html; do echo $(cat "$f" | sed -n '2p' | grep -o 'http://.*\.html') $(stat -c %y "$f");  done > References.tx
```

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

ref_file='References.txt';
> "$ref_file";

for html in *.html
do
    mtime=$(stat -c %y "$html")
    address=$(cat "$html" | sed -n '2p' | grep -o 'http://.*\.html')
    echo "$address $mtime" >> $ref_file;
done
```